# How to install g3log library in ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04

I use ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and `sudo apt search g3log` returns nothing.

Is there any third party package ? I don't want to build it via source code.

g3log: https://github.com/KjellKod/g3log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

things that are on github are not necessarily built into packages for your distribution and hosted on a PPA or better yet the official ubuntu repos.

sometimes that is true but it's an exception rather than the rule. github is not affiliated with ubuntu, all sorts of projects are hosted there and not even necessarily code.

you'll have to build g3log from source, sorry :/